# Set icon on qpushbutton

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I know, thats a beginners question but I have to tried to solve it with goolge / stackoverflow, but I haven't found a good answer. The problem is, I want to add a icon to a qpushbutton. But it doesnt work / the file is not found?!, where is the problem?

...pro-File

```
[...]OTHER_FILES += \
Readme.txt \
icons/newFolder.png \
icons/newFile.png
```

class.cpp

```
//toolbar
QToolBar *tool = new QToolBar();
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton();
btn->setIcon(QIcon(":/icons/newFile.png"));

tool->addWidget(btn);
addToolBar(tool);
```

Best regards :D Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding PNG files to your project doesn't have any effect. You need to create a resource file and add your files to it. After doing this you can access resource data using `":/icons/newFile.png"` notation.

See [The Qt Resource System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/resources.html).

Comment: This helped... but it still still didn't work for me until I deleted the output directory and recompiled (even cleaning didn't work).